# get category names beloging to the post id in coma

Tags: php, mysqli

i have 3 tables tbl_post, tbl_category, tbl_post_category

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_post` (
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `tbl_category` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `tbl_post_category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

i am able to fetch all the details like post_title, post_category but its showing properly and duplicating and getting result as bellow

[image]

and i want to result categories coma separated as below
[image]

my code is bellow

```
    <?php
$i=0;
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_post JOIN tbl_post_category ON tbl_post.post_id = tbl_post_category.post_id INNER JOIN tbl_category ON tbl_post_category.category_id = tbl_category.category_id
ORDER BY tbl_post.post_id DESC");
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);                           
foreach ($result as $row) {
$i++;
?>
<?php echo $i; ?>
<?php echo $row['post_title']; ?>
<?php echo $row['category_name'];?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `GROUP BY` plus `GROUP_CONCAT()` :

```
SELECT 
    tbl_post.post_id
    , ANY_VALUE(tbl_post.title) as title
    , GROUP_CONCAT( tbl_category.category_name ) as post_categories_names
    FROM tbl_category
        JOIN tbl_post_category on
            tbl_category.category_id = tbl_post_category.category_id
        INNER JOIN tbl_post  ON
            tbl_post_category.post_id = tbl_post.post_id 


    GROUP BY tbl_post.post_id
    ORDER BY tbl_post.post_id DESC
```

Upd: you don't even need two+ queries for your needs. You can fetch all the data required with a single one. I mean the outer `SELECT * FROM tbl_post` is redundant.